# RewriteRule for https not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https

I'm attempting to get my site to load the https version no matter where the user comes from or what they type in (ie: none example.com).

I have the following code within my htaccess file, but it does not load the site as https://example.com if I just type in example.com. I have cleared my cache and turned cloudflare to developer mode.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

Before I had this line in it too, but it caused a redirect loop.

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]


ErrorDocument 404 /404custom.php

<ifmodule deflate_module.c>
    DeflateCompressionLevel 1
    DeflateBufferSize 8096
    DeflateMemLevel 8
    DeflateWindowSize 8

    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
</ifmodule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpg A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/bmp A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/ico A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/ico A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/icon A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000

    # Add a far future Expires header for fonts
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000

    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
        Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>

RedirectPermanent /test_index  https://example.com
```

Comment: "^www" portion of the RewriteCond does not match your input of https:// example.com. Try https:// www .example.com or modify the condition. (having trouble with SO's markdown)

Comment: Do you also want to remove `www` with `https://`?

Comment: @anubhava Yes. No matter what the user types in www or not, I want it to say https://example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an orphan `RewriteCond` that is not valid. Also you need an `OR` clause like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. I cleared the browser history, did ctrl + f5, and went to a different browser.

Comment: Your updated answer takes an example.com to the https version, but it throws an error the example.com redirected you too many times.

Comment: I cleared my cache and used multiple other browsers to check. I just posted all of my htaccess in my question.

Comment: This is really weird. Whenever I take out your code, the site goes to the https version by just typing in example.com...however, if I put your code in, I get the redirect error.

Comment: Nvm my last comment. I am on a different computer now. The site is going to https regardless, but it won't load the page. It still says there are too many redirects.

Comment: Ah you have `Server: cloudflare-nginx` instead of Apache

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know that mattered. I literally just switched to it an hour before posting this, so don't know too much about it yet.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for all of the help you have given!